# Why don't we use <script src='xyz' /> in HTML5?

Tags: html

The HTML5 tutorials I am currently looking at use

```
<script scr='lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>'
```

instead of

```
<script scr='lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' />
```

Is there a specific reason why the shorter version is not used?

Comment: your question is, shorter version is used in html5 ? or shorter version is not used in html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. The empty elements tag is only valid in [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480). In [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag) `<script />` just means `<script>` and not `<script></script>` So you are not closing your script tag in HTML5. That said, there are a [number of self closing tags in HTML5](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html). You can use for instance `<br />` it will be interpreted as `<br>` because it is a self closing tag that does not need to be closed. The tailing slash is added to make it look like XML.